# Select an h2 by innertext

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selector

I want to select an element (h2) by its inner text. My page has 3 h2 (1) 'title' (2) 'the text I want to select' and (3) 'something else'. I want the h2 (2) 'the text I want to select'

```
let [myH2] = [...document.querySelectorAll('h2')].filter(item => item.innerText === 'This is the text I want to select');
```

It works fine but it only selects the first h2 and I want to select the second one.

Comment: Select via CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript j08691 :)

Comment: First check h1 hasn't hidden and special characters, Next try use ```textContent``` instead innerText, and change value to lower for case sensetive chars.

Comment: It worked perfect!!!!!! :) thank you!